# How to format a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In one column (E) I have values such as `2014-10-28 19:40:00+00:00`. This is obviously date and time.

In my (F) Column I want to just use the date from that, so I've used the formula `=LEFT(E:E,10)` which worked nicely.

In my (G) Column I want the time, so I used `=RIGHT(E:E,14)` and it shows up with "19:40:00+00:00" which is what was expected.

Now I am trying to format the cells to have the time show up in a standard format of `hh:mm`. When I right click and select this format, nothing happens.

Is there a way to format the output of a formula or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RIGHT` and `LEFT` return strings, return them to their numeric values using the `VALUE` formula

```
=VALUE(LEFT(...))
```

Should allow you to use custom formats again

Answer (score 1):

If **E1** contains:

```
2014-10-28 19:40:00+00:00
```

Then in **G1** enter:

```
=MID(E1,12,5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your value in E is a date value, then `=INT(E1)` will extract the date, and `=MOD(E1,1)` will extract the time

If your value in E is text, then `=INT(DATEVALUE(E1))` will extract the date, and `=MOD(DATEVALUE(E1),1)` will extract the time

Both will be in recognized formats for excel, and can then be formatted in any way you desire